# charts js grid line not removing

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to remove gridlines from my chart that i have created using chrts.js but it is not working and verything seems right but i dont understand what is wrong, here's the code, i'll be grateful if someone could help me

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                    drawTicks: false
                  },
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all gridlines from the chart area, you should define the option `gridLines.drawOnChartArea: false` for the y-axis **and** the x-axis.

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 5
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: actually i just wanted to remove gridlines on yaxis, but your code did helo me because i noticed i was using chats,js version 3 ans when i changed it to what you are using my code ran just fine , i was importing this version before - <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-alpha/Chart.min.js"></script> , thanks a lot for your answer